# What happens if I disable Google app?

Tags: google

If I disable Google app (which came preinstalled on my phone and which I don't use) will that have an effect on other apps by Google like Google Maps or Gmail?

I want to disable it for privacy reasons but I don't want other apps to be affected.

Comment: Causes bootloop in a Nexus phone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it won't have any affect on other Google apps. I have it disabled in my phone.
Here are the things I can't use anymore:

1. Search widget at homescreen. I have removed it anyways.
2. Google assistant.

I've basically never missed anything with the Google app disabled. Maps, Gmail, contacts sync and everything else works as they should. I don't see them having any connection with Google app.

However there will be issues if you disable Google Play Services app.

Comment: Today I found out that disabling the Google app not only removes the Search widget, but some others as well. I.e. *At a glance* (calendar and weather), *Feed* (not sure what this is, maybe an older version of *At a glance*) and *Google sound search*